# Kotlin NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/serialization/KSerializer with mockk and kotlinx.datetime

Tags: datetime, kotlin, mockk

I’m using kotlinx.datetime and mockk.
I would like to mock `TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()` at a below code, but error occurs, `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/serialization/KSerializer`
When `mockkObject(TimeZone)` was called, the error happened.

Why happens error, and how to solve?

Enviroments

- kotlinx.datetime 0.2.1
- kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 1.5.21
- mockk 1.12.0

```
class MyTest {
    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mockkObject(TimeZone)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        unmockkAll()
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        every {
            TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()
        } returns TimeZone.of("Asia/Tokyo")

        assertEquals(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault(), TimeZone.of("Asia/Tokyo"))
    }
}
```

```
Aug 20, 2021 7:43:20 PM io.mockk.impl.log.JULLogger warn
WARNING: Failed to transform class kotlinx/datetime/TimeZone$Companion
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/serialization/KSerializer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
...
```

Comment: This issue was solved by [the comment](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C9EJFT6DB/p1630013429001700?thread_ts=1629456620.014200&cid=C9EJFT6DB) in Kotlin slack.  

kotlinx-datetime higher than `0.2.0` has depend kotlinx-serialization, but it declared `compileOnly`.
Runtime has no dependency of kotlinx-seriliazation when calling `mockkObject()`, so the error occured.  

I added `testRuntimeOnly org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.2.2` in build.gradle and the test was successful.